# How to Filter By More Than One Option Ath The Same Time, Checkbox

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have set up a checkbox filter. I am filtering by brand or type. With my current code I can filter either by brand or type but not brand and type.

I want to be able to filter by brand and type.

I thought I had figured this out but lack of sleep is killing me and I can't seem to wrap my head around this problem at the moment so any help would be much appreciated.

---

My current code:

guns.jsx

```
const Guns = (props) => {
  const { guns } = props

  if (!guns) {
    return (
      <Layout>
        <div className="flex justify-center items-center min-h-vh">
          <Image src="/loading.gif" width={500} height={300} />
        </div>
      </Layout>
    )
  }

  const [checkedInputs, setCheckedInputs] = useState({})

  const handleInputChange = (event) => {
    setCheckedInputs({ ...checkedInputs, [event.target.value]: event.target.checked })
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('Checked Inputs', checkedInputs)
  }, [checkedInputs])


  // Get categories for the Gun filter.
  const getCategories = () => {
    const findCategories = guns.map(gun => {
      return gun.Type
    })

    const filterCategories = findCategories.filter((category, index) => findCategories.indexOf(category) === index).sort()

    const categories = filterCategories.map((cat, index) => {
      return {
        categories: {
          catID: index,
          name: cat
        }
      }
    })

    return categories
  }


  //Get brands for the Gun filter.
  const getBrands = () => {
    const findBrands = guns.map(gun => {
      return gun.Make
    })

    const filterBrands = findBrands.filter((brand, index) => findBrands.indexOf(brand) === index).sort()

    const brands = filterBrands.map((brand, index) => {
      return {
        brands: {
          brandID: index,
          name: brand
        }
      }
    })

    return brands
  }



  return (
    <Layout>
      <div className="flex mx-96">
        <div className="w-1/4">
          <GunFilter categories={getCategories()} brands={getBrands()} handleInputChange={handleInputChange} checkedInputs={checkedInputs} />
        </div>
        <div className="w-3/4">
          <div className="grid grid-cols-3 gap-2 lg:my-12 lg:justify-center">
            {guns.map(gun => {
              if (gun.ImageCount > 1) {
                // If no options boxes selected
                if (Object.keys(checkedInputs).length < 1 || Object.keys(checkedInputs).every(value => checkedInputs[value] === false)) {
                  return <GunProductCard gun={gun} />
                }

                for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(checkedInputs)) {
                  if (value === true) {
                    if (key === gun.Type || key === gun.Make) {
                      return (
                        <GunProductCard gun={gun} />
                      )
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            })}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Layout >
  )
}

export async function getStaticProps() {
  const res = await fetch(process.env.GUNTRADER_API)
  const data = await res.json()
  const guns = data.Guns

  return {
    props: {
      guns
    },
    revalidate: 600
  }
}
```

GunFilter.jsx

```
const GunFilter = (props) => {
  const { categories, brands, handleInputChange, checkedInputs } = props

  return (
    <div className="text-black my-24">
      <h4 className="p-2 border-b-2 border-r-2 font-bold">Filter By</h4>
      <div className="p-2 my-2 border-r-2 border-b-2">
        <h5 className="mb-2 font-semibold">Category</h5>
        {categories.map(cat => {
          return (
            <div>
              <input type="checkbox" id={cat.categories.name} value={cat.categories.name} checked={checkedInputs[cat.categories.name]} onChange={handleInputChange} />
              <label key={cat.categories.name} className="ml-2" htmlFor={cat.categories.name}>{cat.categories.name}</label>
            </div>
          )
        })}
      </div>
      <div className="p-2 my-2 border-r-2 border-b-2">
        <h5 className="mb-2 font-semibold">Brand</h5>
        {brands.map(brand => {
          return (
            <div>
              <input type="checkbox" id={brand.brands.name} value={brand.brands.name} checked={checkedInputs[brand.brands.name]} onChange={handleInputChange} />
              <label key={brand.brands.name} className="ml-2" htmlFor={brand.brands.name}>{brand.brands.name}</label>
            </div>
          )
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default GunFilter
```

Comment: You can just use the `&&` and pass the brand and type. With what you have done already that should be easy. In place of the `||` use the `&&`

Comment: That's what I thought. It doesn't work though. When using && nothing is returned, when selecting the filters.

Comment: I think the main issue is with the for-of over the `checkedInputs` you're only looking to match one condition ***OR*** the other in any given loop iteration. It would make more sense to use array.prototype.filter first, then map the results. Nsoseka is correct that you want a logical &&, but you need to **AND** all your filtering conditions at the same time.

Comment: I agree. Do you mean use .filter to filter out the value === true?

Comment: No, something like `guns.filter(gun => conditions ? conditions.every(...) : true).map(...`.